What exactly is the difference between a cover (motivation) letter or a statement of intent?
In the context of application to a PhD position in a specific research group? I have tried googling it but haven't been able to find any concrete answers. Also if they are different, what are the general formats of both?

How is the "Statement of Intent" described? Is it the more typical "Statement of Purpose"? Is it focused on the institution or on the field and research goals?

@Buffy Yes I think it is like a "Statement of Purpose" but more focused towards the future research goals and fit with the institution.
